# Explicit route model binding in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

So up until recently this has worked, until I wanted to change it slightly. I have a route

```
Route::get('/courses/{course}/lessons/{lesson}', 'CourseLessonController@show')->name('frontend.course.lesson');
```

I want the `{lesson}` to now refer to order_number, not the `id` column.

I've tried this in my RouteServiceProvider

```
Route::bind('lessons', function ($course, $lesson) {
    return App\CourseLesson::where('order_number', $lesson)
    ->where('course_id', $course->id)
    ->first();
});
```

I also tried going the `getRouteKeyName` route, this could be working, except for the fact that it doesn't ensure the lesson record is part of the course `{course}` is binding to.

```
public function getRouteKeyName() {
    return 'order_number';
}
```

None of them work, it still seems to link to the `id` column. It isn't even ensuring the column `course_id` in the lessons table is the same as the `{course}` passed to the route...

Here is my controller method:

```
public function show(Course $course, CourseLesson $lesson) {
    return view('frontend.lessons.show', compact('lesson', 'course'));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to StackOverflow :)

Just going to respond to these:

> I also tried going the `getRouteKeyName` route, this could be working, except for the fact that it doesn't ensure the lesson record is part of the course `{course}` is binding to.

and

> None of them work, it still seems to link to the `id` column. It isn't even ensuring the column `course_id` in the lessons table is the same as the `{course}` passed to the route...

It sounds like you've got it working with `getRouteKeyName` (great!), but your concern is that it doesn't validate that the lesson is part of the course.

This isn't the purpose behind the route - you should handle that logic in your controller.

For example:

```php
public function show(Course $course, CourseLesson $lesson) {

    // Confirm that this course/lesson combination is valid
    if ($lesson->course_id == $course->id) {
        return view('frontend.lessons.show', compact('lesson', 'course'));
    }

    // The lesson is not in this course
    return redirect(route('home'));
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this doesn't really fix my problem, but is a dirty workaround. It makes no effort to match it with the course, and it never will. Therefor it will never work the way I want it to, because it will always hit an `id` before `order_number`.

Comment: This would be the conventional way of handing this logic in a Laravel application.

I wouldn't recommend putting the logic into the routes file, because it's not the place another developer would expect to find it (e.g. if you hire someone to help with the app in the future).